# Incorporating existing Python program into Django website

Tags: python, django

I need to convert an existing desktop python application into a Django powered website. To do this I will likely have several Django apps each performing certain things.

What im not sure about is where to put all the existing python files for each app. Each app will require several existing python files. For a basic Django app most of the program logic would be in views.py. However the desktop application that I will be converting is large with several python files. In other words, I can't just dump the entire application into the views.py file of a Django app.

My thinking is that inside views.py I would make calls to the various existing python files stored in a sub-directory. Im just not sure what is best practice in terms of where to put all those files? Can I just create a new folder in an app for example called 'program' which will contain all the python files.

I presume the files shouldn't go into static, because that should be used for pdf's, css, etc?
Should it possibly go into templates?

Just trying to find out this is typically done. Let me know if I haven't explained myself clearly enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can make `views.py`, `models.py`, etc. modules instead of single files.
You can also add other modules such as `core`, `helpers`, you name it, to contain business logic code that is not necessarily a view.

For example, my relatively large django app has roughly the following structure:

```
my_app
  views
    __init__.py
    example_view_1.py
    example_view_2.py
    some_module
      __init__.py
      another_view.py
    ...
  models
    (all my app's models)
  helpers
    (helper modules)
  backends
    (authentication backends)
  forms
    (django forms)

third_party
  (all third party packages - I use GAE so I must upload them)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks very much. I wasn't entirely sure how much freedom we have in terms of creating our own directory structures within Django. I wondered if there was a specific place to put something like this,...but that seems to not be the case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you include in your project.  There are fixtures in the naming convention like `views.py`, `models.py`, `admin.py`, the standard stuff but then there are addons for packages you import into the project via settings (like `tasks.py` for [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/)).

It all depends on the complexity of your project thou.  I'm working on an so large that we decided to break `models.py` up into several files in a models directory.  `__init__.py` in that directory imports the models from each file.

[Two Scoops](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) is basically a styleguide on how to write Django code.  I recommend it.